# Connection to SQL Server fails if executed from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, sql-server, teamcity

I've got a little C# app that drops and re-created a database for my tests to run. This app is executed in TeamCity that runs under `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` user.

Here is my application:

```
    public void SetupDatabase()
    {
        var childConnectionString = "Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=MyDatabase;Uid=Tester;Pwd=Tester;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";

        var masterConnectionString = "Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=master;Uid=Tester;Pwd=Tester;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";

        Console.WriteLine("Using child connectionString: {0}", childConnectionString);
        Console.WriteLine("Using Master connectionString: {0}", masterConnectionString);

        Console.WriteLine("Connection for master using this user: {0}", GetUser(masterConnectionString)); // <- this one shows NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

        Console.WriteLine("Connection for child using this user: {0}", GetUser(childConnectionString)); // <- this one fails saying 
        // Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.
        // Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
    }

    private string GetUser(string connectionString)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            var command = new SqlCommand("select SYSTEM_USER", connection);

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var user = reader.GetString(0);
                return user;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

I'm specifying SQL Server username/password in the connection string, why is  `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'`?? I'm not using Windows Authentication.

Fair enough, `System` account will fail to login to `MyDatabase` because it is not set up on that database.

Funny thing - when I execute the same application myself I get no exceptions and my username is printed

```
Connection for master using this user: MACHINENAME\trailmax
Connection for child using this user: MACHINENAME\trailmax
```

Why-oh-why is username/password from the connection string are ignored and trying to login as Windows-Auth.

p.s. the user `Tester` is set up on `MyDatabase` and when I go to SSMS and use credentials from the connection string, I can login and can execute all the commands I need. The problem appears when I run the same executable from TeamCity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of `trusted_connection=true` from the connection string

Comment: Can't believe this is that simple! Took me hours to debug. Thank you!

Comment: There are 4 correct and very similar answers. So I have accepted the one that was submitted first. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You set `Trusted_Connection=True`, which means use windows authentication. If you want SQL authentication, then set `Trusted_Connection=False`.

Comment: Can't believe this is that simple! Took me hours to debug. Thank you!

Comment: There are 4 correct and very similar answers. So I have accepted the one that was submitted first. I would have accepted them all, but SO does not allow for this -(

Answer (score 2):

Take `Trusted_Connection=True;` out of your connection string. This overrides any user name or password.

Then have a think about your security architecture - do you really want to be hard coding and compiling logins and passwords into your windows servce?

Comment: That worked! can't believe I have not played with this! Regarding architecture - the actual code is more complex. Just showing a minimal reproducible snippet here.

Comment: There are 4 correct and very similar answers. So I have accepted the one that was submitted first. I would have accepted them all, but SO does not allow for this -(

Comment: Thats fine no problem.... I'm curious as to why you don't want to use the service account credentials to connect but obviouslyit's more complicated than I can see.

Comment: You mean use Windows Auth in SQL Server? Security reasons mostly - this is executed on a build server and I don't wan accidentally drop the wrong DB - every project gets their own DB with their own SQL-user.

Comment: So you might have 100 project databases and 100 SQL users, and it'snot practical to create those users as windows users.

Answer (score 2):

Remove trusted_connection=true from your connection string as that is gonna override the user name you have configured. In the case of Windows Services, it's gonna use NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.

Comment: Can't believe this is that simple! Took me hours to debug. Thank you!

Comment: Also be careful with MultipleActiveResultSets=True. You should only use when you are really opening multiple nested readers.

Comment: Never considered that, just copied the connection string from other project and changed the creds. I'll change it. Thanks!

Comment: There are 4 correct and very similar answers. So I have accepted the one that was submitted first. I would have accepted them all, but SO does not allow for this -(